# How to access my webpage with rosbridge server?

Tags: ros, rosbridge, rosbridge-server, server, websocket

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to create an application for control my robot through Internet. I am using raspberry Pi 4 and ROS1 noetic under ubuntu. The wifi connection is the same between raspberry and my laptop during the test. I can’t establish a connection to my webpage. Could you please help? I was following this example - https://roboticsknowledgebase.com/wiki/tools/roslibjs/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/406251/how-to-access-my-webpage-with-rosbridge-server?/) by [tiho_bg](https://answers.ros.org/users/55794/tiho_bg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-09-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-09-10**:\

> How to access my webpage ... ?

Just open the page in your favorite internet browser.

> I can’t establish a connection to my webpage.

What is the error? Make sure you can ping the rosbridge server machine from your browser machine.

*Nevertheless, I feel that information is lacking in this question.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You seem confused about what rosbridge_server does. According to the wiki page, it creates a websocket that your browser (or other client) can connect to. With a websocket server, you can NOT simply type the websocket url into your browser and "see the page."

The usual approach is that you write javascript code, add the code to an html file, then you read that html file with your browser. The html file can be stored on the local disk, or you can read it from an http server that you run yourself. If written correctly, the javascript code inside the html file will make a connection to the rosbridge_server.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2022-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tiho_bg](https://answers.ros.org/users/55794/tiho_bg/) on 2022-09-16**:
Thank you for your help. Everything is working fine now!